# ASP.NET Local Resources Localizacion

Tags: asp.net, localization, resources, local

We use resx files to localize my web applications. 
We have created a bunch of resource files under different APP_LocalResource folders and
we are accessing that resources from pages and user controls through meta:resourcekey.

We want to move all the resource files into one folder, without changing meta:resourcekey

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

i think it's not possible without change meta:resourcekey. but you can put in App_GlobalResources folder and used by direct assign to text property.

Example:

```
<asp:Literal ID="lblSearch" Text="<%$Resources:GeneralResource, General_Search%>" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```